# Can't increase my partition size due to start

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian

I saw today that my computer didn't want to boot because my /dev/sdb2 (/ partition) was totally full.
That was a big mistake from me, I've set the size at 10G, which isn't enough.

I started from the Debian 8 (which's my OS) install CD, and now I'm on an install shell. And Something is going wrong.

I want to increase my /dev/sdb2 size, here's the ouput of `fdisk -l`:

```
Device     Start     End         Sectors     Size    Type
/dev/sdb1  2048      1050623     1048576     512M    EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   20582399    19531776    9.3G    Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  20582400  53938175    33355776    15.9G   Linux swap
/dev/sdb4  53938176  1836517375  1899586959  905.8G  Linux filesystem
```

so /dev/sdb2 is mounted on /, and /dev/sdb4 on /home.

I tried decrease /dev/sdb4's size, and increase /dev/sdb2's but this changed the start and caused a catastrophic error. Mistakes made me learn !

Now my problem is: how can I do to increase /dev/sdb2's size without changing his start (and lose everything) and without changing any other start too?

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot into a GUI from that install disk and launch [gparted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual)? 
If so, then I would suggest doing so; if not, then please create a bootable, LiveUSB using the image from http://gparted.org/livecd.php, using another PC.

In these changes, cylinder mapping is preferred if it the drive is an HDD; MB mapping if it is an SSD.

I believe you hit a snag when you tried to alter multiple partitions at once, so instead, let's make changes one step at a time, and make sure that when we move a partition, we move it towards the end of the drive, and there is blank space between it and the partition before it.

Either way, once you have gparted launched, resize /dev/sdb4, shrinking it by 10GB. That partition should still end at the end of the drive. Make that change by itself, and apply it.

Resize the swap partition, /dev/sdb3 so it starts and ends 10GB later. Make that change by itself, and apply it.

Now, you should see a 10GB gap between the end of /dev/sdb2 and the beginning of /dev/sdb3.  You can now proceed to extend /dev/sdb2 out another 10GB.

Also, are you using a BIOS or UEFI configuration for your disk and its boot record? Looks like UEFI... could you please [verify that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_HDD_in_UEFI_mode) from a terminal window with

> [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Installed in UEFI mode" || echo
>   "Installed in Legacy mode" ?

What, exactly is the failure message when you try to boot? Does it complain about [the lack of a BIOS Boot Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition)?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
How can I create a LiveCD without any CD/USB and from command line ? :/  
The only thing I have in recovery mode is a shell...
I tried what you said, but with fdisk: decreased the swap partition to 5.9G, and then increased the /dev/sdb2 to 20G,  but this doesn't worked.

Comment: also tried to decrease the swap to 10.9G, if it was a space problem... And problem is still here.

Comment: cylinder alignment has been obsolete since the late '90s: any concept of chs geometry is completely fabricated.

Comment: Please advise the error you experience and the complete text which occurs when you try to boot from the HDD.